# Unable to launch pods on Kubernetes cluster(from airflow DAG)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow

I have an airflow DAG whose tasks Im attempting to run on an AWS EKS cluster.The dag tasks are built as docker images and uploaded to AWS ECR.

The dag task:

```
task_1 = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                               image="XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/com.YYYY/math-demo:v1",
                               labels={"foo": "bar"},
                               name="math-test",
                               task_id="math-task",
                               get_logs=True,
                               dag=dag
                                )
```

The docker image(on ECR) is of the form **"XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/com.YYYY/math-demo:v1"** and the local docker image is **math-demo:v1**

When I run this task the pods are always in a pending state and never execute.I ran **kubectl describe pods** and get the following error:

> Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to set up sandbox container "620ee0494e7aaf1776120df10351606c2203c194ca86079fd7198d56fabbc79b" network for pod "math-test-fbdab794": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "math-test-fbdab794_default" network: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50051: connect: connection refused", failed to clean up sandbox container "620ee0494e7aaf1776120df10351606c2203c194ca86079fd7198d56fabbc79b" network for pod "math-test-fbdab794": NetworkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod "math-test-fbdab794_default" network: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50051: connect: connection refused"]

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: seems like it's do with the EKS CNI provider (pod possibly not being assigned an ip address). Not exactly sure there's anything you can do (except call support). Does the rest of the cluster work fine? Have you tried reproducing on a new cluster?

Comment: @eamon1234 It works fine on my local minikube Kubernetes cluster.I will contact the owner of the EKS cluster then-Thanks!

Comment: hey @user5347996, did you found a solution ?